# jsp- How to concatenate a string and a variable?

Tags: jsp

I wrote a simple line of code that looks like below:

```
  if (autype.equalsIgnoreCase("Superuser")) {
    str += "<input type=\"radio\" name=\"usertype\"" +rowid+ "value=\"Superuser\" checked> Superuser ";
```

`rowid` is a variable declared as 0. What I am trying to achieve is getting the usertype to output to say usertype1, usertype2,usertype3,etc by increment.

When I run the code and I inspect the element of the name, it shows:

```
<input type="radio" name="usertype" 2value="Superuser">
```

What I want is `name="usertype2"`. And I can't seem to get the concatenate to be part of the name itself. Am I doing anything wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your concatenation should be this way.

```
 if (autype.equalsIgnoreCase("Superuser")) {
    str += "<input type=\"radio\" name=\"usertype"+rowid+"\"  value=\"Superuser\" checked> Superuser ";
```

Comment: Just check the difference between your way and my.